# How do I get programmatically (SSOM) all tasks by the Work Management Service Application?

Tags: tasks

How do I get programmatically (SSOM) all tasks by the Work Management Service Application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way:

add this dll (Microsoft.Office.Server.WorkManagement.dll) to the references of your project. You will find this dll in the GAC. The code below shows all tasks which are not completed yet.

```
private void ShowMyTasks()
        {
            // Get current context
            var context = Microsoft.SharePoint.SPServiceContext.Current;

            // Gets the session manager
            UserSettingsManager usm = new UserSettingsManager(context);
            Microsoft.Office.Server.WorkManagement.UserOrderedSessionManager osm = new UserOrderedSessionManager(context);

            UserOrderedSession uos = osm.CreateSession();

            // Create a new task query
            Microsoft.Office.Server.WorkManagement.TaskQuery tq = new TaskQuery();

            // Set completed filter
            var taskFilter = new TaskFilter()
            {
                CompletedCriterion = new BooleanCriterion() { CompareType = BooleanCompareType.IsFalse }
            };

            tq.FieldFilter = taskFilter;

            // Read filtered tasks from the task session

            TaskClientCollection tcc = uos.ReadTasks(tq);

            // Set datasource and bind
            taskRepeater.DataSource = tcc;
            taskRepeater.DataBind();
        }
```